# Image does not store on Firebase and the crop dont open

Tags: android, image, firebase, crop, firebase-storage

I want to pick a picture with the Crop library (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) and then I want it to store in Firebase.

The problem is that after I choose the picture on the default gallery crop does not open and the picture is not saved on the Firebase storage. 
What have I made wrong? (I cut out not important things in the code)

```
package com.cryneo.lobby;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private CircleImageView mImage;
    private Button mImageBtn;
    private static final int GALLERY_PICK = 1;

    private StorageReference mImageStorage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.settings_image);

        mImageBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.settings_image_btn);
        mImageStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        String current_uid = mCurrentUser.getUid();



        mImageBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryintent = new Intent();
                galleryintent.setType("image/*");
                galleryintent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(galleryintent,"Bild auswählen"), GALLERY_PICK);



            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && requestCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                    .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                    .start(this);

        }
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("profile_images").child("profile_image.jpg");

                filepath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Perfekt", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Fehler", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }
                });

            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it works now. I just made an typo. Instead of requestCode it must me resultCode

```
 if (requestCode == GALLERY_PICK && resultCode== RESULT_OK) {
```